# Vaadin minimize external JavaScript during compilation

Tags: javascript, gwt, vaadin

My Vaadin widget is using external JavaScript code that is kept under widget's `public` directory. During widgetset compilation this JavaScript is copied to `VAADIN\widgetsets\...` directory.

I'd like to keep javascript code readable and long in source directory (`public`) but minimized in destination directory (`VAADIN\widgetsets\...`). In other words I'd like to add external JavaScript minimization step to widgetset compilation.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: How are you currently including the script in your widget? Are you using Maven, Ivy, Ant, something else?